# Oracle SQL split column using string functions

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

In a table(football_team) the values in a column(names) looks like this `Andrew Luck , QB` . I want to split this column into 3 columns first_name,Last_name,position using PL/SQL functions.
i tried this

```
select regexp_substr(names,'[^ ,"]+',1,1) as first_name,
regexp_substr(names,'[^ ,"]+',1,2) as last_name,
regexp_substr(names,'[^ ,"]+',1,3) as position from football_team;
```

doesn't work
Can I make it by using only `SUBSTR` and `INSTR` functions.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could use string functions too but IMO regexp is much simpler here. Well as long as you can read regexps, YMMV.

The problem is in regular expressions. Try this instead:

```
with names(name) as (
 select 'Andrew Luck , QB' from dual
 union all
 select 'John Doe , WB' from dual
)
select
 regexp_substr(name, '^([[:alpha:]]+)', 1, 1, '', 1) as firstname
,regexp_substr(name, '^[[:alpha:]]+[[:space:]]+([[:alpha:]]+)', 1, 1, '', 1) as lasttname
,regexp_substr(name, '([[:alpha:]]+)$', 1, 1, '', 1) as position
from names
;
```

Returns:

```
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME POSITION
--------- -------- --------
Andrew    Luck     QB
John      Doe      WB
```

The firstname matching regular expressions explained:

```
^ -- start of the string
 ( -- start of subexpression group that is referenced by regexp_substr parameter #6 (subexpr)
  [ -- start of matching character list
   [:alpha:] -- character class expression: alphabet.
  ] -- end of matching character list
  + -- matches one or more occurrences of the preceding subexpression 
 ) -- end of subexpression group
```

The explanantion of other two regexps are left as an excercise for the OP.